# LASSO and Dimension Reduction

Tags: lasso, dimensionality-reduction

Is there a way to use LASSO for dimension reduction by choosing only relevant attributes? Is there a defined procedure for doing it optimally? Is there a example dataset that can be used for it?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I think  you'll have to describe your dimension reduction problem / domain of application in more depth in order to get a good answer...

Comment: You may use the wine dataset in R as an example:
wine <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", sep=",")
  
  # Name the variables
  colnames(wine) <- c("Cvs","Alcohol","Malic acid","Ash","Alcalinity of ash", "Magnesium", "Total phenols", "Flavanoids", "Nonflavanoid phenols", "Proanthocyanins", "Color intensity", "Hue", "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines", "Proline")
  
  # The first column corresponds to the classes
  wineClasses <- factor(wine$Cvs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, LASSO can be used for reducing the number of attributes. Using **cross-validation to select the optimal value of lambda** to be used for the LASSO would be a good idea. The following example is from the book "[An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf)". It uses the glmnet library for performing LASSO and the **Hitters** data set from ISLR

```
library(glmnet)
library(ISLR)

attach(Hitters)

x = model.matrix(Salary~., Hitters)[,-1]
y = Hitters[row.names(x),]$Salary

set.seed(1)
train = sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x)*0.75)
test = (-train)
y.test = y[test]

# values of lambdas to use
grid = 10 ^ seq(10,-2, length=100)

lasso.model = glmnet(x[train,], y[train], alpha=1, lambda=grid)
plot(lasso.model)

# Using Cross Validation to find the best lambda
lasso_cv_model =cv.glmnet(x[train,], y[train], alpha=1, lambda=grid)
plot(lasso_cv_model)

best_lambda = lasso_cv_model$lambda.min
best_lambda

pred = predict(lasso.model, s=best_lambda, newx=x[test,])
mean((pred-y.test)^2)

lasso.coef = predict(lasso.model, type="coefficient", s=best_lambda)[1:20,]
lasso.coef[lasso.coef!=0]   
# only non-zero coefficients
```

The above mentioned book explains LASSO in detail - page 219. Also check out the lab exercise.

Comment: +1 Nice example, answering the question well. The danger, of course, is that if predictors are correlated then the particular choices among them by LASSO (or any variable-selection method) can vary substantially from sample to sample. That might not be a big problem for prediction in many cases, but there is a danger that someone might try to infer that the particular predictors chosen are really the only "relevant" ones. It's often good to repeat the LASSO on multiple bootstrap samples of the data to get a handle on the variability of predictor selection.

Answer (score 1):

The are a few ways, the simplest may be AIC, BIC etc. But I would suggest you to use out-of-sample performance to select the best $\lambda$ then see which attributes' coefficients are 0s in the best model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please add code (preferably in R) that might show how I can you the LASSO for dimension reduction in the Wine dataset as an example?

Answer (score 1):

LASSO, as it is, is not a good way to screen-out noisy covariates, for the reason mentioned above (correlations among covariates), but not only. Unless you have a truly strong signal in the dataset, you will never be able to screen out only the relevant covariates unless you adjust the procedure. Also, it is well known that cross-validation with LASSO leads to overfitted solutions (although the prediction performance-wise usually works well), so be careful with it too.

I think the best reference is: https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/christian.hansen/research/Lasso%20paper%20draft%201_28FINAL.pdf. They provide detailed discussion and example codes (with STATA and R).