# When is LASSO better in dimension reduction?

Tags: pca, lasso, dimensionality-reduction, spectral-analysis

Are there any cases that it is better to use Lasso for dimension reduction in comparison to other methods such as PCA/ Kernel PCA/ LLE and ISOMAP and SPECTRAL EMBEDDING?
Can you add an example (most preferably in R) to show its benefits over the other methods?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do in more detail? It's hard to interpret your question because lasso and the other methods you mentioned solve different classes of problems.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to understand in what cases it is better to use Lasso is for dimension reduction in comparison for other methodologies. You can refer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283952/lasso-and-dimension-reduction.

Comment: LASSO-type of methods imposes certain conditions on your regression function coefficients (e.g. sparsity), while PCA and other methods will assume dense signals. The efficiency of dimension reduction will depend on your data characteristics.